# Laravel 5.2 + upload file and save name in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

In laravel 5.2, I could upload file using below code but could not find a way to store uploaded filename in database.

```
    $destinationPath = "test/";
    $file = $request->file('profile_pic');
    if($file->isValid()){
        $file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['profile_pic']->pathname = $destinationPath.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $user->update($request->all());
    }
```

Does anyone know how to store filename in db?

Comment: $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();This is how to get the name of file and this is how you merge it to inputs   Input::merge(array('file_name' => $filename ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that. Silly Mistake!!

need to replace line from

```
$input['profile_pic']->pathname = $destinationPath.$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

to

```
$input['profile_pic'] = $destinationPath.$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Answer (score 7):

Code for uploading files/images and writing real names into database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    if($file = $request->file('your_file')){

        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('folder_where_to_save', $name);
        $data['your_file'] = $name;

    }

    Model_name::create($data); // where $data can be $request->all() or you can manually assign the fields you need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, It wiil help you:

```
$destinationPath = "test/";
    $file = $request->file('profile_pic');
    if($file->isValid()){
        $file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['profile_pic']->pathname = $destinationPath.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $user->update($request->all()); // Remove This

        // Add this lines

        $data['YOUR_DB_FIELD_NAME'] = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $user->update($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Check this full code

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$extension = Input::file('prd_img')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension;
Input::file('prd_img')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
$data = array(
    'prd_name' => $prd_name,
    'prd_cat' => $prd_cat,
    'prd_sub_cat' => $prd_sub_cat,
    'prd_img' => $fileName,
    'remember_token' => $remember_token,
    'created_at' => $time,
);
if(DB::table('products')->insert($data)){
    return redirect('add-product')->with('success', 'Product Succssfully Added.');
}else{
    return redirect('add-product')->with('error', 'Something wrong please try again.');
}
```