# how to upload an image and get it's url in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-6

I know this should be the most basic stuff in the world, but somehow I can't make it work. I have a model Category that has an image field

This is the code the uploads the file

```
$uploadedFile = $request->file('image');
$fileName = time().$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $uploadedFile->move(public_path().'/uploads/categories', $fileName);
$category->image = $path;
$category->save();
```

when I try it out, it actually uploads the image but doesn't show the correct url I want to use the url in a img tag like this

```
<img src="{{$category->image}}" class="img-fluid"/>
```

when I print the url I get something like this

```
"C:\Projects\duars_web\public/uploads/categories\15822290505.png"
```

which of course wont work on a img tag...any clue on why is that happening? and how to get a proper url to my uploaded file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 + upload file and save name in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109411/laravel-5-2-upload-file-and-save-name-in-database)

Comment: Because `public_path` returns a _file system_ path. You don’t want a file system path, you want a URL. You are probably looking for something like `asset()`, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset

Comment: file upload is okay but for database you should only store path.

Comment: "which of course wont work on a img tag..." Wrong. That's the path to the image and it obviously will work in `src`.

Comment: @Qumber Rizvi it might work...but I don't feel exposing my filesystem structure is a good practice....

Comment: @CBroe I need the path to call asset() but not the whole path from my filesystem but the relative path no?

Comment: @PrateikDarji nah, that question ask about saving the filename not the url to the file....

Comment: @AbidHussain's answer tells you how to use `asset()` to give relative path in `src`. Additionally, when deployed on a server, your absolute path will probably be like this: `example.com/images/...`

Comment: @AnibalCardozo Can you explain what is relative path in your mind? Is it `uploads/categories\15822290505.png` only or any thing else? Please explain more so I can help you. I have another method for you but need to explain more.

Comment: @QumberRizvi I tried on the server but my absolute path was something like this 

`/var/www/production/duars_web/public/uploads/categories/158228529835.png `

Comment: You don't have to worry about that. The image would be servable at a path relative to the public folder of your repo. However I would like to suggest you to not keep uploads inside the repo. Give services like S3 a try.

Comment: Try `<img src="{!! asset($category->image) !!}" class="img-fluid"/>`or `<img src="/uploads/categories/{{ $category->image }}"`

Comment: @TalhaF. I got this when I use asset()

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/C:\Projects\duars_web\public/uploads/categories\1582292175123.png`

and sadly don't work

Comment: @AnibalCardozo you need to insert on table onl image name with extension

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="{!! asset('images/uploads/categories/logo.svg') !!}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert only your image name with extension in table :

```
if($request->hasFile('image'))
{
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $image_name = time().$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/categories');
  $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);
}

$user = new User;
$user->image = $image_name; // Save only file name
// More data
$user->save();
```

Then on your blade :

```
<img src="{!! asset($category->image) !!}" class="img-fluid"/>
```

or

```
<img src="/uploads/categories/{{ $category->image }}" class="img-fluid"/>
```

Hope this helps.